# How to remove more than one rows from layout?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I add widgets to layout and then add this layout as a row to another layout:

```
lbl = new QLabel(this);
    currentResistorText += tr("Resistor") + tr("#") + QString::number(resistorCounter);
    lbl->setText(currentResistorText);

    newResistorLayout = new QHBoxLayout();

    lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);

    newResistorLayout->addWidget(lbl);
    newResistorLayout->addWidget(lineEdit);

    ui->resistorsLayout->insertRow(fieldCounter, newResistorLayout);
```

I do it in slot, so there can be added multiple rows.

When I try to remove one row it works.

Here is the code:

```
ui->resistorsLayout->takeRow(ui->resistorLayout->rowCount() - 1);

    delete lbl;
    delete lineEdit;
    delete newResistorLayout;
```

If I try to remove the second row then program just crashes. I also tried to use the removeRow() method, but result was the same. What am I doing wrong?  And how can I remove more than one row?
I'm using Qt 5.8.

Answer (score 0):

From Qt documentation:

`[pure virtual] QLayoutItem * QLayout::takeAt(int index)`

Must be implemented in subclasses to remove the layout item at index from the layout, and return the item. If there is no such item, the function must do nothing and return 0. Items are numbered consecutively from 0. If an item is removed, other items will be renumbered.

> The following code fragment shows a safe way to remove all items from a layout:

```
QLayoutItem *child;
while ((child = layout->takeAt(0)) != 0) {
    ...
    delete child;
}
```

Hope it help.